# javascript: getting a function's return that is called by another function

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to insert a date between div tags by calling `checkDate()` but I don't believe it's returning what I want, which is `formatDate()`'s return.  I am currently getting nothing coming back between the div tags but when I console log the `formatDate` function, I know it's been hit because the log is printing out.

```
function formatDate(date) {

     return "the date is" + date;
}

function checkDate(date) {
      let newDate = date
      return this.formatDate(newDate)
}


<div>{{ checkDate(date) }}</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `this` to call the function?

Comment: As @AdarshMohan say, you dont have to use the `this` keyword to call the function. Now, the semicolons are optional

Comment: Just to know. Is this part of any angular code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function formatDate(date) {
     return "the date is" + date;
}

function checkDate(date) {
      let newDate = date;
      return formatDate(newDate)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>{{ <script type="text/javascript">document.write(checkDate(new Date()))</script> }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output on my system:
{{ the date isWed Mar 20 2019 11:13:50 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) }}

So your setup seems fine. IT must be the external environment that does not output the return value of checkDate.